# Java char/int conversion confusion

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

Given this code in Java:

```
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test.dat");
    os.write(0x14);
    os.write(0xfe);
    os.write(0xae);

    os.write(String.valueOf((char) 0x14).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    os.write(String.valueOf((char) 0xfe).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    os.write(String.valueOf((char) 0xae).getBytes("UTF-8"));

    os.write("\u0014".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    os.write("\u00fe".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    os.write("\u00ae".getBytes("UTF-8"));

    os.close();
```

Can somebody explain to me why the first 3 bytes in test.dat are

```
14 fe ae
```

while the output from the last 6 os.write()'s are

```
14 c3 be c2
```

Basically, I want to literally output the bytes 14 fe ae.  I was storing these values as a String constant, and writing the value of these constants to a UTF-8 file, but 14 c3 be c2 was output instead. There's obviously a gap in my understanding in how these byte sequences are converted in Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It gives:

```
0x 14 fe ae 14 c3 be c2 ae 14 c3 be c2 ae
```

The first three bytes are obvious.  They're just being outputted literally.  For the next three, you should remember that char in Java represents a UTF-16 code unit, not a byte.  So you're first creating the Unicode code units U+0014, U+00FE, U+00AE, then converting each to UTF-8.  U+0014 is 0x14 in UTF-8 (since it's also ASCII), but U+00FE is 0xC3 0xBE and U+00AE is 0xC2 0xAE.

You're creating the same characters again in the next three lines.

The bottom line is that if you want to store literal bytes, just use a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

`"\u00fe"` is not the byte `0xfe`, it is the Unicode code-point `0xfe`, which when encoded in UTF-8 can become a multi-byte value (as shown above).

Answer (score 0):

You missed a byte: you should be getting `14 c3 be c2 ae`.

For your last six `os.write` calls, internally Java is storing each character in a one-character Unicode string. When you call `getBytes` this gives you the UTF-8 representation of these characters. For U+00FE (`þ`) this is `c3 be`, while for U+00AE (`®`) it's `c2 ae`.